# bcrypt.compare() is asynchronous, does that necessarily mean that delays are certain to happen?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, bcrypt

I'm using the [bcryptjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcryptjs) package to hash and compare passwords.

The `compareSync` method used below is synchronous and returns a boolean.  It is reliable and works as expected.

```
let trueOrFalse = bcrypt.compareSync('abcd', '1234');

if(trueOrFalse) {
    console.log('hooray, it was true');
} else {
    console.log('oops, it was false');
}
```

The next example uses the asynchronous `compare` method.  I'm concerned that because this version is async if there is any delay on the server it may get to the `if/else` statement before `bcrypt.compare` has determined the value of `res`.  Is this a valid concern or am I misunderstanding the nature of this type of async function?

```
let trueOrFalse;
bcrypt.compare('abcd', '1234', function(err, res) {
    trueOrFalse = res;
}

if(trueOrFalse) {
    console.log('hooray, it was true');
} else {
    console.log('oops, it was false');
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Asynchronous method will be executed in parallel with your main program, so your `console.log` will be done before the callback function inside `bcrypt.compare`. You will see always 'oops, it was false'.

You can wait for the real result in your main function and then show something in console.

To make comparison 'waitable' you can wrap it into `Promise`:

```
function compareAsync(param1, param2) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        bcrypt.compare(param1, param2, function(err, res) {
            if (err) {
                 reject(err);
            } else {
                 resolve(res);
            }
        });
    });
}

const res = await compareAsync(param1, param2);
console.log(res);
```

I prefer to wrap legacy callback functions into Promises because it will save an app from a [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com).

Comment: "*you should wait in your main thread*" - that's not possible. The proper mitigation of the problem is to defer the `console.log` to the future (when the async task has completed) by putting it inside the callback.

Comment: Yes. You are completely right. But it could be more comfortable to use async/await syntax. So you will not appear in a callback hell at some moment ).

Answer (score 2):

The Node.js runtime will surely run the synchronous code (the if-else statements) before you get the result from the async computation. You are guaranteed that the computation is completed only **in** the callback function:

```
bcrypt.compare('abcd', '1234', function(err, res) {
    // make your checks here
    if (res) {
      // ...
    }
})
```